# IndexError: list index out of range, scenario is different

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have this error occurring, and I could find multiple stackoverflow posts on the error, and I am able to relate the explanation given in those posts.But my scenario is different.
I am executing below python code in Spark 1.6.1 environment::

```
  1 from pyspark import SparkContext
  2 sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")
  3 from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
  4 sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
  5
  6 ssn = sc.textFile("/Data/amitesh")
  7
  8 parts_ssn = ssn.map(lambda l: l.split(','))
  9 #wow = ssn.map(lambda ())
 10
 11 stg_ssn = parts_ssn.map(lambda p: Row(name=p[0]))
 12 stg = sqlContext.createDataFrame(parts_ssn, ['name','age','city'])
 13 stg.take(5)
```

The error that I receive is pointing to the line 12. 
I have 3 txt files under /Data/amitesh in my hdfs environment with 3 columns each. All of the 3 files have same schema, i.e. name,age,city.There is no heading in the files though.But number of rows might differ.

Below is the full stack dump

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/iop/4.2.0.0/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/iop/4.2.0.0/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1_IBM_4-hadoop2.7.2-IBM-12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "location_to/master.py", line 16, in <module>
    stg = sqlContext.createDataFrame(parts_ssn, ['name','age','city'])
  File "location_to/context.py", line 423, in createDataFrame
  File "location_to/context.py", line 315, in _createFromRDD
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am using spark-submit to execute the code

spark-submit --master local master.py

Any suggestions please....!!

Comment: My expected output is to see the column content for 5 rows

Comment: What does line 315 of `context.py` look like?

Comment: that file seem to be a part of .zip dir called pyspark.py when I try to go that location, which I guess is a default supporting directory for pyspark console.

Comment: Looks to me like you are creating rows which only have one column (name) but then while creating the dataframe give a schema with three columns (name, age, city). So maybe you need to adjust your lambda to `lambda p: Row(name=p[0], age='', city='')`.

Comment: Okey, the error vanished. Thank you @LiMuBei

Comment: Good. I posted the comment as answer for you to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting comment as answer since it solved the problem:

When preparing the RDD to convert it to a DataFrame, the created Row entries contain only a single column (`name`), but when creating the DataFrame, the provided schema contains three columns (`name, age, city`).

The columns in the Row objects need to match the provided schema when creating the DataFrame. So it should look like this:

```
stg_ssn = parts_ssn.map(lambda p: Row(name=p[0], age=p[1], city=p[2]))
stg = sqlContext.createDataFrame(parts_ssn, ['name','age','city'])
```

This assumes, that `p` contains three entries of course.